# The type or namespace DbContext could not be found (EF installed)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext, csproj

I making simple EntityFramework with MVC application. My solution has 3 projects

- GE.BLL
- GE.Entities
- GE.Web

Everything looked great until i decided to rename GE.BLL to GE.Core

so i removed the whole project and added all classes and references again from scratch to GE.Core. Now my EntityFramework for this project is installed and System.Data.Entity is also referenced but does not compile

"The type or namespace DbContext could not be found"

**My app.config is**

```
    <configuration>
   <configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

and packages.config is

```
<packages>
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

i am using framework 4.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I uninstalled EntityFramework and re-installed it!

Comment: yes!! (i can only accept it as an answer after 1 day )

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was working with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.  The problem seemed to be that, when I initially created the project, I mistakenly put it within a .NET Core Web project.  I had subsequently moved it up a level in the folder hierarchy outside of the web project.  That is when I started seeing this error.  Uninstalling and reinstalling the NuGet packages did not seem to work and Visual Studio's suggested fix was to reference dlls in the "nugetfallbackfolder" directory under Program Files.

Long story short, I ended up creating a brand new project and then everything worked just fine (after referencing the necessary Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore NuGet packages, anyhow.